# How to do element wise addition on two list using Cypher on Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have two nodes and each of those nodes have a property called embedding which is basically a list of numbers. Now I want to do element wise addition of these two lists.

So basically [1,2,3] + [1,2,3] = [2,3,6]

Just directly adding does not work because addition of lists is not supported.

Here is the cypher query to replicate the two nodes -

```
CREATE (note:Note { name: 'note_1', embedding: [1,2,3]})
CREATE (note:Note { name: 'note_1', embedding: [4,5,6]})
```

I want the end result as `[5,7,9]`

Preferably without using any third party libraries that are not supported in both the community and professional edition of Neo4J

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the most performant approach, but this query will do the trick.

```
MATCH (n:Note)
WITH n, size(n.embedding) as length
WITH length, collect(n.embedding) as embeddings, count(*) as count
UNWIND range(0,count - 1) as i
UNWIND range(0, length -1) as j
WITH j,apoc.coll.sum(collect(embeddings[i][j])) as sums
RETURN [x in collect(sums) | toInteger(x)] as result
```